# Bootstrap Modal appears inside another scrollable window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Let me show you an image of what I'm talking about

[image]

It's really weird since I'm using a very similar code to the one shown in a tutorial.

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "My Routine";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml";
    
}

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Tracking de Agua</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>Actualice la cantidad de agua que ha ingerido:</h4>
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">

                        @foreach (var property in Model.VisibleProperties())
                        {
                            using (Html.ControlGroupFor(property.Name))
                            {
                            @Html.Label(property.Name.ToSeparatedWords(), new { @class = "control-label" })
                            <div class="controls">
                                @if (property.Name == "Quantity")
                                {
                                    @Html.Editor(property.Name, new { @class = "input-small" })
                                    <b>Lts</b>
                                    @Html.ValidationMessage(property.Name, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
                                }
                                else if (property.Name == "Date")
                                {
                                    { Model.Date = DateTime.Now; }
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Date);

                                }
                            </div>
                            }
                        }
                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                }

                <hr>

                <h4>Recomendaciones</h4>
                <p>Se debe mantener una correcta hidratación cuando se realice una actividad física ya que puede producirse un aumento de temperatura corporal y sufrir un golpe de calor. </p>
                <p>Es fundamental evitar la sensación de sed bebiendo líquido a lo largo del día, ya que cuando ésta aparece quiere decir que ya se ha producido cierto grado de deshidratación en el organismo. </p>
                <p>Se deben consumir alimentos ricos en agua como las frutas y verduras, caldos, sopas, gazpachos… </p>

            </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Can someone enlighten me as to why this is happening and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Are you sure you've included Bootstrap 3.x? Looks fine on here: http://www.bootply.com/WdWJROYFK3

Comment: You are right it's probably an older version. The problem is that this project is relatively big and several people are working on it right now so I'm afraid changing it to a newer bootsrap is going to have an effect in other parts I'm not working on. There has to be solution for this though.

Comment: Use this older modal markup instead.. http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals It would look something like this: http://www.bootply.com/3uOeUB9xjz

Comment: Thanks, this is much better! Just had to remove the hide class for it to work.